# Android: Can I override a third party class (library) that has its own layout?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-library, android-inflate

I found a really good calendar library on github which I would like to use. It has its own layout.

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

There is certain UI functionality that I would like to change but I do not want to write my own calendar from scratch. Is there a way I can override this library? What I have tried so far is producing an error.

I tried to extend this class like so:

```
public class MyCustomCalendar extends MaterialCalendarView {

    public MyCustomCalendar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

Then I am using `MyCustomCalendar` class as a view in a `ConstraintLayout` like so:

```
<com.example.test.MyCustomCalendar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and I am inflating this layout in a `Fragment` of the `MainActivity` like so:

```
public class CalFragment  extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
    }

}
```

This is, however, producing an error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test, PID: 19357
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.example.test.MyCustomCalendar
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.example.test.MyCustomCalendar
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

It looks like I cannot make my own XML layout like above why is that?

Comment: well, you can clone this library locally and change it ?

Comment: did you miss this part of the doc? https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview#customization

Comment: what part of the doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may not be related to the library. You need to implement these constructors for custom view:

```
public MyCustomCalendar(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyCustomCalendar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyCustomCalendar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

When you use the view in xml, the system will use the second or third constructor instead of the first one.

Comment: That did solve the error you were right. Which one will it use though? or any logic I write in a constructor I should include in all of them?

Comment: Having the second constructor should be enough in this case. You can read more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int)